# SVM and Linear models disadvantage

Tags: machine-learning, linear-model, svm

I was reading about SVM and linear models, I found that one of the disadvantage is SVM and Linear models do not perform well when the number of rows (instance) less than the number of columns (features)?
I was reading several days about the SVM to understand why but I could not.

Kindly would anyone explain why they "number of rows less than the number of features" is disadvantages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think this is true, provided the regularisation parameter C is properly tuned.  Note that the SVM is an approximate implementation of an upper bound on the generalisation error that is independent of the dimension of the feature space.  This is one of the reasons why SVMs with non-linear kernels (with infinite dimension feature spaces) still work well.  Of course an SVM used badly may well perform badly.  The same is true for ridge regression, which I often use rather than the linear SVM.

Comment: in fact several website indicated that including geeks for geeks "In cases where the # of properties for each data point outstrips the # of training data specimens the support vector machine will underperform."  and thehttps://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html   "If the # of features is much greater than the # of samples, avoid over-fitting in choosing Kernel functions and regularization term is crucial."  they are stating that SVM underperform when the # of features more than the # of instance. Yes, the solution for this problem is turning kernel functions well. but why it is problem?

Comment: AFAICS, they are saying the same thing I am.  In that situation "choosing ... the regularization term is crucial".  For problems of that nature, a linear kernel is likely to work as well as any other (in the absence of prior knowledge), so there probably isn't much to be gained by tuning the kernel, especially if it adds more hyper-parameters.  As I said, I would normally use [kernel] ridge regression rather than a standard SVM as tuning the regularisation parameter is much easier using the "ridge trace" method (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.neunet.2007.05.005)

Comment: essentially if you are not tuning the C parameter carefully, you are not using the SVM correctly (and shouldn't be surprised if it works badly) as the tuning of the C parameter is what gives rise to structural risk minimisation.  Note the SVM has frequently been used successfully for micro-array data where there may be several thousands of features but only a hundred or so samples.

Comment: "In cases where the # of properties for each data point outstrips the # of training data specimens the support vector machine will underperform."  Can you give a URL for that one?  As it stands, it is flat wrong, and demonstrably wrong (c.f. microarray analysis).  It may be that there is some missing context (but also be wary of blog content, it isn't always written by someone that knows what they are talking about).

Answer (score 0):

Problems with more features than samples are going to be a problem for *any* machine learning method or statistical classifier.  This is because the number of parameters will generally increase with the number of features, and the more parameters you have, the more data you will need to estimate their values reliably.  There is no critical point where this goes from being fine to being a problem - it depends on the nature of the data generating process (i.e. the problem) and potentially also on the classifier.

Now the linear SVM will have less of a problem with this sort of dataset than most.  Assuming the data are in *general position* (e.g. no co-linear points), then a linear classifier is guaranteed to be able to split the training sample without error if there are more features than samples.  However, the SVM (with C equal to infinity) will give you the maximal margin classifier, which separates the data in such a way that the deviation from the training data required to produce an error is as large as it could possibly be.  Thus it is likely to generalise better than some randomly chosen decision boundary that has zero error on the training set.

**However** you may still get better performance by tuning the regularisation parameter, C.  This is because the structural risk minimisation principle aims to select a model from a hypothesis class that is as small as possible.  Increasing C increases the size of the hypothesis class (the number of linear models that can be represented), so we can chose a less complex classifier by reducing C.  We start with a very powerful classifier, e.g. a linear model in a high-dimensional space, and reduce it's power by putting a constraint (C) on the norm of the weight vector.  So we match the complexity of the model to match the complexity required by the learning task.

Tuning the C parameter is central to the correct application of Support Vector Machines, so if you are not tuning it carefully (e.g. using a [default setting](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.06777.pdf)) you are using it incorrectly and it may not work very well.